# show bottom of UICollectionView when view is loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have problem with UICollection view

I have chat window, messages are preloaded and stored in core data, so i have access to them in view controller at the very beginning of view controller's life cycle.

The problem is that when chat window is opening user can see how all message stack i scolling from top to the last message at the bottom

What logic should i use to have user experience of loading view as for example in facebook messenger app (when user sees last messages immediately without any flickering) ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your viewDidLoad, get the indexpath for the last item in your collection view, then:

```
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO]; // Has to be animated:NO
```

Comment: I can't understand why but it does not work. View won't to scroll

Comment: I have managed to achieve the effect you suggested by switching offset and inset of collection view. The problem is that i still can see top cells then pause then bottom. I want view to load with bottom cells at the start

Comment: @Roma did you find the answer yet? I'm working on the same problem now. Thanks.

Comment: @Marku Yes. I've found how guys from slack did this 
https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController  look at this file https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController/blob/master/Source/Classes/SLKTextViewController.m and check self.inverted and method - (void)setInverted:(BOOL)inverted   They are basicaly inverting tableView Or collection view - so your top is no bottom - and everything will happen automaticaly)) but not to forget do the same with cells and not view for header it is view for bottom and vice versa